# Firebase Realtime Database listeners doesn't fire in offline-first mode on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I execute goOffline() at the beginning (in AppDelegate) like that:

```
Database.database().goOffline()
```

And create some default data in code.
I'm expecting that listeners for that data is going to fire and data should be available but it doesn't happen.

Listener example:

```
ref!.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
  // handle snapshot here            
}
```

If I comment out **goOffline()** on first launch then everything works like a charm - even .childAdded events.
Problem is related only to **first launch** in **offline** mode. (looks like Firebase requires online mode to create local data structure or etc)

How to handle that?

*By default app should be in offline mode and online mode must be available only to premium users.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable persistence ?
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
Take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Yes persistence is enabled. It even works after first run in offline mode. The problem is related only to first run.

Comment: Did you also enabled sync for that specific node?

Comment: No, looks like isPersistanceEnabled enables sync for all nodes - all of them are accessible in airplane mode. Let me try that approach, thanks!